# How to asynchronously communicate between server and client

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Okay, this code handles the server side communication between a server and client. I am not too familiar with boost::asio, but I tried my best following the several tutorials. However, there remains one problem when trying to communicate between my client (I haven't built it yet so I'm using putty) and the server. The server only receives data when the client closes it's connection. I'm just wondering if that is suppose to be the case, and if so how do I respond to client side requests?

This is the function to start the server (it is shortened, i removed the error handling mechanism)

```
void Initialize(){
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    Network network(ioservice);
    ioservice.run();
}
```

Here is the function that starts accepting connections

```
void Network::StartAccept(){
  Connection::pointer new_connection = Connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

  acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->getSocket(),
     boost::bind(&Network::HandleAccept, this, 
     new_connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

This function handles the accept and starts another accept again

```
void Network::HandleAccept(Connection::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code & error){
if (!error)
{
    //sio::cout() is one of my functions that automatically time stamps everything and ends the line if needed
    sio::cout("Client Connected from Origin: ", false);
    sio::cout(new_connection->getSocket().remote_endpoint().address().to_string(), true, false);
    new_connection->start();
}
else {
    sio::cout("Could Not Accept Connection to Client");
}
StartAccept();
```

}

This function handles client I/O

```
void Connection::start() {
//message_ = "Hello World";

//boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_), boost::bind(&Connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, msg, boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

}

I would like to be able to write "hello world" to the client and then read in what the client says, however if I do `async_write` (which is commented out), it disconnects the client and `async_read` spits out an error because there is no connection

**TLDR** how do I keep the connection open, or am I not suppose to

Comment: Are you using telnet to talk to server ? The use of `putty` is unclear to me? Also, `The server only receives data when the client closes it's connection`..I guess here you `async_read` handle is getting invoked with 0 bytes to read, in that case the server received a `RST` packet from client indicating close of connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, originally I wanted for the client to send information to the server and then the server to respond. I figured out how to do it. @Arunmu helped me figure that PuTTY was causing some problems, due to the fact that when he pointed it out I looked deeper into it.

It turned out PuTTY was closing the window and not displaying the server side messages because it deemed the exit as successful. The only thing I had to change was the last function I posted.

```
void Connection::start() {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, msg, "\n",
     boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
     boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

}

The function works as I want it to, at least to some extent. The client I have to write will just have to create a new connection every time it wants to ask the server something.